# OCR an image knowing the font beforehand

Tags: fonts, ocr

I need to retrieve a lot of old data which is stored as a series of images. They all have the same background and text colors, all use Verdana in the same font size. Something like this:

[image: Example text]

What I've tried was counting pixels in a column and matching a single glyph to my previously "encoded" glyph database. Worked pretty good, but there were two major problems

1) keming - to separate glyphs I checked if I hit a space between characters. This didn't work when two characters overlapped. I solved it by adding to my database all combinations of kerned letters
2) Aliasing - this is my ultimate problem - a single letter can look in many different ways because of aliasing, and almost every aliasing case looks unique, so I can't build a database of "those sorta look like an A" without completely changing my recognition code approach

So: Is there a tool for recognizing specific font on an image which handles aliasing well?

*I'd really appreciate solution other than using tesseract, it's my last choice due to complexity and weight*

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the simplest way is to use good OCR tool for that. I plugged this image into demo page of [OCRSDK.com](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Demo/) and it was handled perfectly. 
[image]
It is commercial, but has some free amount of recognitions so you could play arround and decide if it works for you. It is web API, so plugging into your application is very easy, and there are [code samples](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples/) availabe.

So, it might be good enough already without any font training. However, if accuracy is still not enough, then you may want to look into font training. But this is quite complicated process for any OCR engine. However, still way easier that to invent your own OCR.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY